# how to resolve the issue for Merge conflicts on GitHub, not locally?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

anyone has experience seeing the conflict on PR on github but not one local feature branch?
the step I have is

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature/aaa
modify some file, a on feature branch
git add file && git commit "message" & git push
at the same time, someone modify file on master
create a PR, then github show "PR cannt be merged" some conflicted
```

I research online and see lots of people have the same experience,[Merge conflicts on GitHub, not locally?](http://%20https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Merge-conflicts-on-GitHub-not-locally/td-p/7184)
 but I do not see any solution. I appreciate all input

btw,I cannt change git flow since it is department development process with CI/CD

Comment: This *shouldn't* be a problem if everyone is following Git Flow (or a similar equivalent). GitHub bases the 'conflict' state from when the branch is created, *not* the current state, so as long as everyone works on feature branches you should never end up in this state. Having said that, I would consider branching features from `develop` and only treating `master` as the last known 'good state'. As for the actual problem, [*this article*](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github) may help.

Comment: what if someone also cut their feature branch from master after I cut it and modify the file back to master before me. i can understand we should have conflict but i do not understand is why i can see conflict on github but not on my local branch after I checkout master, git pull, checkout feature/mybranch and git merge master

Answer (score 0):

try doing git pull origin <branch_name> with the branch you want to merge

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).